Why is the preferred competing response for eye blinking tics keeping the eyes closed?
The most common competing response suggested during HRT for eye blinking/squeezing tics is keeping the eyes closed for 4-5 seconds until the urge to tic passes away. Why is this preferred over the more obvious competing response of just keeping the eyes open until the urge passes away? For example, in most other types of motor tics, the recommended competing response is tensing the body part and keeping it still until the urge to tic passes away. Why isn’t this the case for eye tics?
For research, I have tried searching google and asked ChatGPT and the most plausible response I have got is that keeping the eyes open for an unnatural amount of time leads to drier eyes and more eye strain. However, I feel that the duration of the competing response of keeping the eyes open is insufficient for this to be a concern.

We don't consider that AIs are a useful or credible sources of information at this point in history. Try first Wikipedia as a secondary sources, then the references in Wikipedia should point to primary sources (at least they should, but of they don't, then at least you'll have encountered various ideas and new search terms).
